# pandas.read_clipboard from cloud-hosted jupyter?

Tags: pandas, jupyter, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am running a Data8 instance of JupyterHub running JupyterLab on a server, and `pd.read_clipboard()` does not seem to work. I see the same problem in google colab.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_clipboard()
```

errors out like so:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PyperclipException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8cbad928c47b> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_clipboard()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboards.py in read_clipboard(sep, **kwargs)
     29     from pandas.io.clipboard import clipboard_get
     30     from pandas.io.parsers import read_table
---> 31     text = clipboard_get()
     32 
     33     # try to decode (if needed on PY3)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard/clipboards.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    125 
    126         def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 127             raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)
    128 
    129         if PY2:

PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.org
```

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Pyperclip uses "copy/paste mechanism" specific to your OS to do the actual copying and pasting. As a result, it only works when directly run on a Windows/macOS/Linux system. I'm not sure if there's a workaround for this for JupyterHub.

Answer (score 1):

No. The machine is run in the cloud. Python from there cannot access your local machine to get clipboard content.

I tried Javascript clipboad api, but it didn't work probably because the output is in an iframe which isn't allow access to clipboard either. If it did, this would have worked

```
from google.colab.output import eval_js
text = eval_js("navigator.clipboard.readText()")
```

Comment: it doesn't work because you need to have user action. make it into a button and it works