# Multiple quantile labels for same values in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Metric and I am trying to create new columns containing labels that describe the quantile each Metric value falls into. However, I am finding that, for the same Metric value, I receive multiple quantile labels when I expect them to only receive one.

I have a metric that looks like this:

| Metric |
| --- |
| 5.0 |
| 5.0 |
| 6.0 |
| 5.0 |
| NaN |
| 5.0 |
| 5.0 |
| 2.0 |
| 6.0 |
| 3.0 |
| NaN |
| 2.0 |
| 5.0 |
| 5.0 |
| 5.0 |
| 2.0 |

I want to create new columns that contain the quantile labels for a range of quantiles. This is what I am doing:

```
var_metric = ['Metric']

# Quantile range I am interested in creating labels for
quantiles_list = [2, 3, 4, 5]

# Quantile labels
quantile_2_labels = ['Quantile_2_1','Quantile_2_2']
quantile_3_labels = ['Quantile_3_1','Quantile_3_2','Quantile_3_3']
quantile_4_labels = ['Quantile_4_1','Quantile_4_2','Quantile_4_3','Quantile_4_4']
quantile_5_labels = ['Quantile_5_1','Quantile_5_2','Quantile_5_3','Quantile_5_4','Quantile_5_5']
quantiles_labels_list = [quantile_2_labels, quantile_3_labels, quantile_4_labels, quantile_5_labels]

# Loops for creating label columns
for metric in var_metric:
        for quantile, labels in zip(quantiles_list, quantiles_labels_list):
                df[f'{metric}_Quantile_{quantile}'] = pd.qcut(df[metric].astype('Int64').rank(method='first'), q=quantile, labels=labels, retbins=False)
```

The result looks like this:

| Metric | Metric_Quantile_2 | Metrtic_Quantile_3 | Metric_Quantile_4 | Metric_Quantile_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_1 | Quantile_4_1 | Quantile_5_1 |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_2 | Quantile_4_2 | Quantile_5_2 |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_2 | Quantile_4_2 | Quantile_5_3 |
| 6.0 | Quantile_2_2 | Quantile_3_3 | Quantile_4_4 | Quantile_5_5 |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_2 | Quantile_4_2 | Quantile_5_3 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_2 | Quantile_3_2 | Quantile_4_3 | Quantile_5_3 |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_2 | Quantile_3_2 | Quantile_4_3 | Quantile_5_4 |
| 2.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_1 | Quantile_4_1 | Quantile_5_1 |
| 6.0 | Quantile_2_2 | Quantile_3_3 | Quantile_4_4 | Quantile_5_5 |
| 3.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_1 | Quantile_4_2 | Quantile_5_2 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_1 | Quantile_4_1 | Quantile_5_1 |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_2 | Quantile_3_3 | Quantile_4_3 | Quantile_5_4 |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_2 | Quantile_3_3 | Quantile_4_4 | Quantile_5_4 |
| 5.0 | Quantile_2_2 | Quantile_3_3 | Quantile_4_4 | Quantile_5_5 |
| 2.0 | Quantile_2_1 | Quantile_3_1 | Quantile_4_1 | Quantile_5_2 |

Using column `Metric_Quantile_2` as an example, I expect all cases where `Metric = 5.0` to receive the same label, however you can see in the second column that the labels for the `5.0` value shift between `Quantile_2_1` and `Quantile_2_2`. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Missing `var_metric` declaration. I suppose `var_metric = ['Metric']`?

Comment: Correct. Added that into the code block thanks

Comment: Still, I can't reproduce your example using your scripts. `NameError: name "df" is not defined`. Where did you define your `df`?

Comment: @Mario, use copy the table on your clipboard and use `df = pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: @Corralien sadly, that doesn't work in a cloud-based environment such as [GoogleColab](https://colab.research.google.com/) [ref1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/412721) [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58687491/10452700), so such _copy pastable_ solution like [Pyperclip](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#welcome-to-pyperclip-s-documentation) module has been not a case except for non-VM local machines to reproduce the data.

Comment: @Mario. Try `df = pd.DataFrame({'Metric': [5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 5.0, np.nan, 5.0, 5.0, 2.0, 6.0, 3.0, np.nan, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 2.0]})`

Comment: @jim_jones Would you show explicitly how the expected outputs should be?

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect your code produce the right result because you don't apply `qcut` on `df['Metric']` but on `df['Metric'].rank(...)` which is not the same thing:

```
>>> pd.concat([df[metric], df[metric].rank(method='first')], keys=['Metric', 'Rank'], axis=1)

    Metric  Rank
0      5.0   5.0
1      5.0   6.0
2      6.0  13.0
3      5.0   7.0
4      NaN   NaN
5      5.0   8.0
6      5.0   9.0
7      2.0   1.0
8      6.0  14.0
9      3.0   4.0
10     NaN   NaN
11     2.0   2.0
12     5.0  10.0
13     5.0  11.0
14     5.0  12.0
15     2.0   3.0
```

What works:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.qcut(df[metric], q=quantile, labels=labels, retbins=False)], axis=1)

   Metric        Metric
0     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
1     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
2     6.0  Quantile_2_2
3     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
4     NaN           NaN
5     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
6     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
7     2.0  Quantile_2_1
8     6.0  Quantile_2_2
9     3.0  Quantile_2_1
10    NaN           NaN
11    2.0  Quantile_2_1
12    5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
13    5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
14    5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK
15    2.0  Quantile_2_1
```

What doesn't work:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.qcut(df[metric].rank(method='first'), q=quantile, labels=labels, retbins=False)], axis=1)

   Metric        Metric
0     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK but lucky, rank=5, first quantile
1     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK but lucky, rank=6, first quantile
2     6.0  Quantile_2_2
3     5.0  Quantile_2_1  # OK but lucky, rank=7, first quantile
4     NaN           NaN
5     5.0  Quantile_2_2  # KO, rank=8, second quantile
6     5.0  Quantile_2_2  # KO, rank=9, second quantile
7     2.0  Quantile_2_1
8     6.0  Quantile_2_2
9     3.0  Quantile_2_1
10    NaN           NaN
11    2.0  Quantile_2_1
12    5.0  Quantile_2_2  # KO, rank=10, second quantile
13    5.0  Quantile_2_2  # KO, rank=11, second quantile
14    5.0  Quantile_2_2  # KO, rank=12, second quantile
15    2.0  Quantile_2_1
```

Comment: Thanks! your `pd.concat` change to my original forloop is throwing me a bit but when I remove `.rank(method='first')` from my original forloop, I get the following error: `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([2. , 2.5, 5. , 5. , 6. ]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg`. Any suggestions on how to deal with it?

Comment: On further reading, I see now why the `.rank()` argument was present. It is to deal with these "duplicate" bin eges. Given how few data points I have, it's obviously not ideal to drop them... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges

Comment: The problem is you have many 5, so 5 is set to two quantile: `np.quantile(df[metric].dropna(), q=np.linspace(0, 1, quantile+1))` (quantile=3)` => `array([2., 5., 5., 6.])`, that's why Pandas raised the exception.

Comment: In the end, I decided to switch to `pd.cut` and define "quantiles" based on the range of values rather than `qcut` which tries to create bins with equal numbers of values in each

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `pd.qcut` which tries to put an equal number of observations into each quantile bin. However, if you have many occurrences of the same value which forces some bins to contain more observations than others, it does not know how to deal with this.

This post breaks down the options that you have in this case: [How to qcut with non unique bin edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges)

In the end, I decided to switch to `pd.cut` which takes the min and max of your metric's value range, and then splits the range up into equal size bins, and then puts your observations into these bins. As a result, you end up with a different number of observations in each bin.

This was my forloop in the end:

```
for metric in var_metric:
        for quantile, labels in zip(quantiles_list, quantiles_labels_list):
                df[f'{metric}_Quantile_{quantile}'] = pd.cut(df[metric].astype('Int64'), bins=quantile, labels=labels, retbins=False)
```

I hope that is clear. Thanks everyone for your help!